# i need to calculate a time difference in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet, called “test time stuff”
It uses a script to automatically add the date and time (in colum “B”) , any time you add an entry
Into the event column.

This is the script......

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "E,M/dd H:mm a"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "event";
  var timeStampColName = "date / time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet 
where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = 
updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only 
timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
     var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, 
 timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
   }
}
```

When I do this i would like the “time in hours and minutes between events” to 
Automatically show the time in hours and minutes in that column. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Here is a link to the sheet...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eyrAzpOFKxDHxs05DYovx3NMrl6XaofXsR24Yt9UzlM/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a link to sheet that can be edited...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RqpVOsy2bzgqnhFHV7m1sae10o9pHA5cdEJ5Ijvl2C8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on how flexible you want it to be. If you do not care that a user will enter a value leaving an empty row and then fill in the blank row later, then it's easy. All you need to do is

```
var prevEvent = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue() //get the previous event time
```

Now you do need to be sure you are using an actual JavaScript `date` format and simply calculate the difference. You can read how to do that in one of the examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It's basically the same thing, only your `start` and `end` are defined by the new value you are setting an the previous value. As I mentioned, this will **not** work properly if the last value is let's say in row `5` and someone enters a value in row `7` and then enters something in row `6` afterwards. The next entry in row `8` will only consider row `7` and not `6`.

To work around that, you would need to get all the values with `.getValues()` and then loop through them, selecting which time was the last, but it can be done. Just takes a bit more fidling around with a `for` loop